# Program has no output (408 lines expected), no compilation or runtime errors

Tags: java

I want to use the output of DynamicTimeWarping (DTW) for classification. It turns out that the output of dynamic time warping algorithm still need post-processing. As part of the time aligning process, some single data points of data A will be mapped into several data points on data B. I plan to take the average of those several data points on data A where they are mapped into single data point to data B. The final output would be one-to-one mapped data points between data that has been optimized for similarity. Then I will use this final output for classification.

The input will one file:(index data A, index data B, content data A) looks like:

```
0,0,0.36
1,0,0.23
2,0,0.14
3,1,0.41
4,1,0.44
5,2,0.16
6,2,0.03
7,2,0.09
```

Following is my current code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class dtw_post {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = 655;
        int x = 408;
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        String line =scan.nextLine();
        String[] lineVector = line.split(",");

        int a[] = new int[N];
        int b[] = new int[N];
        double c[] = new double[x];


        for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        {
        a[i]=Integer.parseInt(lineVector[0]);
        b[i]=Integer.parseInt(lineVector[1]);   
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<x; i++){
        c[i]=Double.parseDouble(lineVector[2]);
        }

        System.out.println(dtw_post.lookup(a,b,c));}
        }

    static String[] lookup (int[] a, int[] b, double[] c){

        String[] final_result = new String[c.length];
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){

        if (a[i+1] > a[i] && b[i] == b[i+1]) {
            double[] d = {c[a[i]],c[a[i+1]]};
            double e = average(d);
            final_result[i] = Double.toString(e); 
        }

        else {
            final_result[i] = Double.toString(c[a[i]]);
        }}
        return final_result;
    }

    static double average(double[] data) {
        double sum = 0;
        int number = 0;
        for (double val : data) {
            ++number;
            sum += val;
        }
        return sum / number;
    }

}
```

Program has no output (408 lines expected), no compilation or runtime errors. The cursor in the command line just blinking. Thank you for your time in helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is waiting for input from command line, becuase you have created `Scanner` for `System.in` stream. You need to read file from it.

```
File file = new File("fileName");

  Scanner scannerFile = new Scanner(file);

 while(scannerFile.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scannerFile.nextLine();
        String[] lineVector = line.split(",");

  }
```

Comment: It works. However, it gives output like this: `[Ljava.lang.String;@7e774085
[Ljava.lang.String;@3f8f9dd6
[Ljava.lang.String;@aec6354
[Ljava.lang.String;@1c655221
[Ljava.lang.String;@58d25a40
[Ljava.lang.String;@1b701da1
[Ljava.lang.String;@726f3b58` What else went wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I figured that out. Thanks.

Comment: @ARSN Consider posting about how you fixed your errors next time.